# Multiply context menus on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm trying to manage multiply menus by jquery contextmenu plugin
lackofcarma://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu
on dynamically created elements.

Here I have 2 buttons created dynamically and menus for them are created on left mouse click.

```
<dic id="cont">  </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#cont').html('<button id="1">button #1</button> <button id="2">button #2</button>');


  $('button').on('click', function(e){
        var $target = $(e.target);
    var id = '#'+$target.attr('id');
    $(document).contextmenu({
      delegate: id, // #1 or #2
      menu: [{title:'Menu for'}, {title:id}]
    });
    alert('Created menu for button '+id);
    // now trying to show menu on left mouse click
    // as suggested by https://github.com/mar10/jquery-ui-contextmenu/wiki
    $('button').on('click', function(event){
      if ( event.which === 1 ) {  // left-click
        // Pass click event to `open()`
        $(document).contextmenu("open", event);
      }

      // just trigger event
      $('button').triggerHandler('contextmenu') ;

      // emulate mouse events
      $('button').trigger('mousedown',{button:2}).trigger("mouseup");

      // none  works..
    });         
  });
});
</script>
```

CodePen is here: https://codepen.io/zzmaster/pen/xrKvpm/

So first, left clicking Button #1 we create menu for it and then, right clicking the same button  we can see that menu.
Next, left clicking Button #2 we attach next menu to button 2 and expecting to see it on right mouse click.
But right click on button 2 doesn't work and we can see menu created for 2-nd button (second menu item show button id) on first button right click!

Next mission - I'd like to show menu by left click, not right. There's a code suggested on plugin's wiki page, but it doesn't work. Also I try to emulate events - successless.

I'm totally frustrated...

Comment: Approach is all wrong. Only initialize once and use `beforeOpen` event to modify menu. Read api docs and see this example http://plnkr.co/edit/Bbcoqy?p=preview. Also note `replaceMenu(menu)` method in docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way. You don't have to use IDs to select the elements, just define classes, or use the parent elements as the selector to initialize the `contextmenu` after you dynamically create the buttons:

```
$('#cont').contextmenu({
    delegate: "button",
    ...
```

OR

```
$(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: "#cont button",
    ...
```

You also have a syntax error at `<dic id="cont">  </div>`, change `dic` to `div`.

Now, a fully working example based on your code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#cont').html('<button id="1">button #1</button> <button id="2">button #2</button>');

  $(document).contextmenu({
    delegate: "#cont button",
    menu: [
      {title: "Item 1", cmd: "item1"},
      {title: "Item 2", cmd: "item2"},
      {title: "----"},
      {title: "Item 3", cmd: "item3"}
    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
      alert("select " + ui.cmd + " on " + ui.target.text());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui-contextmenu/1.16.0/jquery.ui-contextmenu.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: OK, just looked for text link.. ))